# WCF URITemplate

Tags: rest, wcf, wcf-rest

I have an operation contract in an existing WCF service. Now I am extending it for WCF REST api and I am getting a lot of errors, the last one in the service is around parameters. My code is as below:

```
    [OperationContract(Name = "Messages", IsOneWay = true)]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        UriTemplate = "/Messages/?id={id}&fileId={fileId}",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, 
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    [Description("Inbound Message")]
    void Messages(Guid id, int fileId);
```

I am getting the error:

> The UriTemplate '/Messages/?id={id}&fileId={fileId}' is not valid;
> each portion of the query string must be of the form 'name=value',
> when value cannot be a compound segment. See the documentation for
> UriTemplate for more details.*

Please suggest what am I missing in the uritemplate?

Comment: Selim Yıldız’s reply is correct, "/Messages/?id={id}&fileId={fileId}" is an invalid template string, and you also need to change Guid to string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `/` before `?` from `UriTemplate` and change `id` parameter to string.

```
[OperationContract(Name = "Messages", IsOneWay = true)]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
    UriTemplate = "/Messages?id={id}&fileId={fileId}",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, 
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
[Description("Inbound Message")]
void Messages(string id, int fileId);
```

See also: [UriTemplate and UriTemplateTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/uritemplate-and-uritemplatetable)

Comment: If I remove the /, I get this error: The UriTemplate '/Messages?id={id}&fileId={fileId}' is not valid; each portion of the query string must be of the form 'name=value', when value cannot be a compound segment.

Comment: I forgot to say, could you please also change `id` parameter Guid to String, and try again?

Comment: Sort of, but as I faced some other issues, so I am waiting to test everything out to see which one works.

Comment: That is okay. Don't forget to mark answer as an accepted if it helped you, so that it helps to others.